# Open serial port, send hex data and await response

Tags: batch-file, serial-port

Let's say I want to pass `0x42` (hex) to a serial port. My serial port is connected to a card vending device.

How do I write it in `.bat` file and then wait for the response of the device itself.

For now I can do is to make the string to hex.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Store the string in chr.tmp file
set /P "=%~1" < NUL > chr.tmp

rem Create zero.tmp file with the same number of Ascii zero characters
for %%a in (chr.tmp) do fsutil file createnew zero.tmp %%~Za > NUL

rem Compare both files with FC /B and get the differences
set "hex="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ('fc /B chr.tmp zero.tmp') do set "hex=!hex!%%a"

del chr.tmp zero.tmp
echo %hex%
```

Comment: What did you try? How does your code look like? Where do you struggle?

Comment: You should be aware that StackOverflow is for seeking help with your failing code, without code your question is currently off-topic!

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the advice. Question updated.

Comment: Thank you for the update, however your script does not attempt to do any of the things you have asked for in your question. It only generates the hex string and for that you could have just provided `echo 0x42`. You are effectively saying, "I want to create a carving of a tiger from a piece of wood; here is the piece of wood". Do you expect that providing the wood fulfills your fair part of the task? I don't! We're not here as your search engine or resource provider, you need to do more!

Comment: something like `echo %hex% >:COM1`? Don't forget to initialize the serial port to fitting baudrate etc (`mode /?`) before